# Destructuring one or many return types from a function ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, yup

I am using a library (Yup) that normally puts errors as key-value pairs, where the values are strings into an object, for me to read and display to the user. The strings are simply error keys for a table lookup of pretty error messages.

```
console.log(errors)

// output

{
  required: "form:error:required"
}
```

I have written some custom functions so that, for certain error keys, I will now return an object looking like:

```
console.log(errors)

// output

{
  minChars: {key: "form:error:minChars", options: {count: 2} }
}
```

I am using i18next where I need to pass a translation key like so:

```
t(key, options)
```

Currently, I have some very ugly code that fetches the translation key from the errors object but then it could be an simple string, or an object with key and options.

My current code to do so is:

```js
const errorObj = isError ? _.get(errors, field.name, '') : ''
let errorKey, errorOptions
if (typeof errorObj === 'string') {
  errorKey = errorObj
} else {
  errorKey = errorObj.key
  errorOptions = errorObj.options
}
```

Without this ugly type-checking, is there no clever destructuring I can do to handle multiple return types?

I have tried returning an array instead of an object, but then I run into the issue of a string being indistinguishable from an array.

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: I don't believe there is a destructuring operation that simultaneously checks for object structure. However, you can destructure, then check if any of the fields are undefined

Comment: That's good readable code, that expresses your intentions explicitly.

Comment: I would agree with @zerkms . Most of the time, you don't want to sacrifice readability with overly-idiomized code.

Comment: It's just that, semantically, I am receiving either one argument or two, where the type of the first argument is always the same (the key) and the type of the second is an object but is optional. So it seems that, somehow, I should be able to show that in code.